# Convert SVG image to PNG with magnification

Tags: conversion, gimp, png, svg, paint.net

How ca I convert a SVG image to a PNG image with magnification and without pixelation?

I have tried to open with Paint.NET ([with a plugin](https://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/27228-scalable-vector-graphics-filetype-plugin-svg-svgz/)) and GIMP but I did not succeed. The final image is not bigger and it is pixelated.

There is several parameters but they do not seem to influence whatever:

[image: Open SVG image with GIMP]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you link to the file? And what about using an actual vector editing application, like Inkscape?

Comment: You can find [the SVG image here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al759hMA7mcuv_0Dmf8n0dkoPnVh5A).
I did not know Inkscape. Thank for the suggestion, I will try this.

Comment: How can I increase my object by 50% in Inkscape, do you know @MichaelSchumacher?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the size of the SVG file is specified as 500 by 500 pixels. When opened in Inkscape, it looks pretty much like the preview (and the result) in GIMP:

[image: SVG file openened in Inkscape - drawing is pretty small]

A look at the Document Properties confirms this: the size of the document is 500 by 500 pixels:

[image: Document properties - yes, 500 by 500 pixels]

This doesn't prevent the file from being brought to any desired size, of course - but you'd have to specify a pretty large image size to get the visible parts to a reasonable size, too. A better approach is to change the document size to the actual drawing, by the button shown in the previous screenshot:

[image: Resizing the document to drawing]

Voilà! The SVG file's width and height are now much smaller, and it is much easier to enlarge the visible parts without dealing with all the extra area. You still have to specify a larger size to get a useful image in GIMP, but you will likely find it much easier to understand what e.g. doubling the size results in.

[image: Resize document, visible parts enlarged]